# Linux emmc - mmc_hs400_to_hs200 failed, error -110

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems

I've installed Debian Stable (and later upgraded to testing) on a 32gb emmc.  I only switched to testing in order to see if the below error would quit happening:

`mmc_hs400_to_hs200 failed, error -110`

Once it occurs a few times, the filesystem changes into read-only mode and the machine needs a reboot (or I guess a remount of the filesystem).  How can I know what that error code means to diagnose further?  Does this indicate some sort of defect with the emmc or does it indicate some sort of configuration error?

Comment: `110` is `ETIMEDOUT`... which implies that the eMMC isn't responding to the command in a timely fashion. What board / system are you using? Are there any other messages around / related to this? This is likely more of a linux driver / electronics question than [tag:debian] or [tag:filesystems].

Comment: It is an Onlogic CL210G-10 system, it is an Intel Celeron N3350 and according to the manual it is a Samsung KLMG2JETD-B04 emmc.

Comment: Is this new hardware, or "old" / used? The [manufacturer page](https://www.onlogic.com/uk-en/cl210g-10/) implies Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 support, have you tried that? Does [this discussion (and log output)](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/10646971/) look similar to what you're experiencing? There's a [patch](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/10646971/#22324619) at the bottom that may help. Please also add more log output to your question.

Comment: ... as a follow up, [`mmc_hs400_to_hs200()`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/mmc/core/mmc.c?h=v5.5.13#n1231) is called exclusively by the retuning functionality. Each of the [`__mmc_switch()`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/mmc/core/mmc.c?h=v5.5.13#n1244) calls will likely timeout after ~500ms, so you might be able to infer which step is having the problem quite easily by counting (i.e: HS400 to HS DDR, HS DDR to HS, or HS to HS200). This might be a support request to your supplier.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm further along than I was.  I'll try a few things and perhaps give Ubuntu a shot to see if it resolves.  It is new hardware, the first of this type I've attempted to use, I may have to reach out to the supplier if I can't figure it out.  I use Debian on all their other stuff I have.